# Manage all Power BI subscriptions

Tags: powerbi

I see there are two ways to get to my subscriptions:

1. open a report, click Subscribe, click Manage All Subscriptions.
2. Click the gear icon, click Settings, click Subscriptions.

Either way, I don't see all of my subscriptions.  Sometimes I don't see any subscriptions.  "All Subscriptions" appears to be limited to my subscriptions in the current workspace.

I can see this becoming interesting:

- An employee has dozens of subscriptions configured, but no longer
  needs one of them.  But they don't remember which workspace it's in.
  I suppose they can click on the Manage Subscription link in the email
  and click the trash can to remove it.
- An employee has left the company, but Power BI continues to send subscriptions to their email address.
- John Manager has never used Power BI, but consumes reports via email that he had an employee subscribe to for him.  He wants to stop receiving a certain email generated by a Power BI subscription.

How can I manage subscriptions across the entire service, both as a user and as a Power BI Administrator?

Comment: As admin you can use REST API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/users-get-user-subscriptions-as-admin

Comment: @msta42a I see that requires {userid}, but I don't see where to get that.  In the PowerShell cmdlets docs I don't see a Get-PowerBIUser and in the POwer BI REST API docs, I don't see a GetUsersAsAdmin.  All of the Get*UsersAsAdmin functions require me the ID of some other thing.  How do I get UserID from the user's email address?  What did I miss?

Comment: To whoever voted this question down... It would be polite to tell me what makes this a bad question.  Is it because I didn't state what I tried?  I have read the documentation and searched for examples and nothing I found leads me to anything tangible I can try.  That's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: userId ->The graph ID or UPN of user (UserPrincipalName); get this from your AD

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's documentation regarding [managing subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-subscribe#manage-your-subscriptions) covers several of your questions and scenarios. To summarize:

As an administrator:

- It covers how you can [audit subscriptions and subscription activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-subscribe#view-subscription-audit-and-activity-logs) as an admin.
- The [Power BI Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin) contains several tools that might be used to review/monitor subscriptions as an admin. For example, it offers calls that allow you to gather subscriptions based on certain reports, dashboards, or users.

As a user:

- (per [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-subscribe#manage-subscriptions)), `To see all your subscriptions across all workspaces, navigate to My workspace and the select the gear icon, Settings and then the Subscriptions tab.`

As far as how you manage subscriptions for users as they are deactivated or when certain users decide they no longer want subscriptions (like your provided 'examples'), that is going to be heavily dependent on how you and your organization manage users and who's responsibility you delegate subscription it to. Since this is heavily opinionated, I will avoid that here, BUT hopefully these links can at least help you determine what that will be for your organization.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Isn't it fun how a search always returns the forums with unhelpful or wrong answers and buries the good stuff?  Using the MS example for activity/audit logging (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-auditing#use-the-activity-log) returns `Get-PowerBIActivityEvent : Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'`.  I have the libraries installed and am using the correct environment in the login call.  Is it possible that not all features are available in GCC (powerbigov)?

Comment: I would be shocked to hear those features are not available in GCC. I highly doubt that is the case, especially given that the powerbigov endpoints are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-govus-overview). If you need assistance troubleshooting your API calls, I would recommend submitting another question with the relevant information. Attempting to do that here in the comments is not the best place.

Comment: The information you provided pushes me forward quite a bit.  But since the system returns bogus error messages (BadRequest = there was no data for that day, but other days with no data produce an empty result set, not an error) and since the output schema changes by day, and because I can only get one day per request, I'll need to fiddle with this for a while to even determine if I can find subscription activities.  Thanks for the help.  I'll get back to this post after further investigation.